# How to prove that a function is injective

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

$f(x)=3x^2-6x+3$ if we see the graph we'll know that it isn't.
Using the definition we have:

$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$

$$3(x_1^2)-6(x_1)+3=3(x_2^2)-6(x_2)+3$$
We get rid of 3 and the we factorize the other $3$

$$x_1^2-2x_1=x_2^2-2x_2$$
Then we factorize $x_1$ and $x_2$

$$x_1(x_1-2)=x_2(x_2-2)$$

Then what?

Comment: Quadratic functions are never injective because they are continuous and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

The example $f(0)=f(2)$ convinces us the function $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that I can prove it with a contraejemplo, but I was curious if there was other way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

$$x_1^2-2x_1=x_2^2-2x_2$$
$$x_1^2-x_2^2-2x_1+2x_2=0$$
$$(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2-2)=0$$
then $x_1-x_2=0$ or $x_1+x_2-2=0$ which shows two cases 
$\boxed{x_1=x_2}$ or $\boxed{x_1=2-x_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = 3x^2 - 6x + 3$

$\implies f'(x)= 6x - 6$

$\implies f'(x) <0 ~\forall x<1$  and $f'(x)>0 ~ \forall x>1$

Thus, $f(x)$ is not strictly increasing or strictly decreasing in its domain, and hence it is not injective.